# How to determine if a getter is defined before accessing it?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I have a set of get functions in JS such as:

```
get UserName() {
    return this.userModel.Name;
}
```

I want the ability to check if the function exist before I call it.
I tried:

```
if (this.UserName == 'function')...
```

but it's always false, since `userModel.name` is a string, `typeof UserName` returns 'string' type and not a 'function'.

any idea how I can accomplish this ?

Comment: That looks like a getter inside an object literal or class, it's *not* a function. Can you please post a complete example?

Comment: If you want to check whether the *property* (regardless whether it's a getter, setter, or plain data property), use `"UserName" in this`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple way to check that `UserName` exists (without calling the getter) is to use `in`:

```
if ('UserName' in this) {
    // this.UserName is defined
}
```

If you need a stronger check where you directly access the getter function, use [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor):

```
var userNameDesc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, 'UserName');
if (userNameDesc && userNameDesc.get) {
    // this.UserName is definitely a getter and is defined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` which returns basically the same data structure that is fed to `Object.defineProperty()` like this:

```
let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, "UserName");
if (descriptor && typeof descriptor.get === "function") {
   // this.UserName is a getter function
}
```

Or, if you want more granular info, you can do this:

```
let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, "UserName");
if (!descriptor) {
    // property doesn't exist
} else if (typeof descriptor.get === "function") {
   // this.UserName is a getter function
} else if (typeof descriptor.value === "function") {
   // property directly contains a function (that is just a regular function)
} else {
   // property exists, but it does not have a getter function and
   // is not a regular function
}
```

You can also test many other properties of the descriptor such as `value`, `set`, `writable`, `configurable`, `enumerable` as described [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor).

Comment: Couldn't you just use `descriptor.get` instead of `typeof descriptor.get === "function"`? According to MDN, the `get`/`set` properties can only either be a function or undefined.

Comment: @str - Yes, probably. I was being extra diligent to be absolutely safe and frankly I thought this better shows what we expect to find there.